# Cheap DIY Zernike-Phasecontrast: Optical Thickness of a inkjet/laser printed contour for phasering?

Tags: optics, visible-light, experimental-physics, speed-of-light, microscopy

Rough guess: Optical Thickness of a inkjet/laser printed contour? Edit

I was wondering if there is any research regarding the refractive index and the height of an inkjet or laser printed contour?

I would like to create a more/less defined phase-object using a transparent foil and a printed pattern. Of course "gray" doesn't mean half of the maximum optical path length wich is possible to print due to the pixelated structure.

Any idea how I could print a phase step? A decrease of the amplitudes transmittance is welcome!

UPDATE:
Application idea: In Zernike-Phase-contrast microscopy there exist a ring-shaped phase mask in the backfocal plane of the microscope objective. My idea was to build a really cheap equivalent with available parts. Thus a "phase-step" which is a relative change of refractive index (in PH-microscopy it's +/- pi/2 depending on central wavelength) could be made by cut-out glass/foil pieces and place them on a substrate or - in my understanding - by printing structures (not necessarily a ring shape) on glass or a foil. This gives phase retardation and amplitude attenuation at the same time.

I've just printed some "grayvalues" on a plastic laying around to measure its phase - will update the result. The ink - of course - formed droplets right away so the phase retardation won't be uniform. Perhaps a laser printer does better job due to "backing" the particles?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about. "Inkjet printed contour" - this will depend on SO many parameters. Are you intending to use ink in your inkjet? The printer settings (and the characteristics of the substrate) will play a major role; and "normal" ink would strongly absorb the light. What, then, do you think of when you say "optical thickness". What application do you have in mind? Are you trying to attenuate light, creating a Fresnel half zone plate? A bit more clarification would be good.

Comment: Do companies that make ink know _exactly_ what that ink does? Of course they do. Billions of dollars in industrial research have been spent on these inks. Did you bother to look at the relevant literature?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sure I know, that billions of dollars have been spend to get the right formular, but perhaps I'm lacking the right keywords to search for "public" research or available papers. I've updated my answer regarding the application.

Comment: ...or perhaps anybody knows a good way to exchange the resin? This one could be a good start: http://nicholasclewis.com/projects/inkshield/ Another resin/ink could provide more phase-retardation and less attenuation.